# Código para salir de ejecución de programa en C

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

Estoy haciendo un código en C en el que pregunto si se desea salir de la ejecución del programa. Si la respuesta en ´s´ o ´S´, se detiene la ejecución del programa correctamente pero si es ´n´ o ´N´ me vuelve a salir pregunta de si desea salir del programa cuando en realidad yo esperaba que saliera del bucle do-while.

A continuación el código:

```
void salir() {
    
    char ch;

    do{ 

         printf("¿Esta seguro que desea salir del programa? (s/n):");
    
         scanf(" %c", &ch);
    
         switch (ch) {

             case 's':

             exit(0);

             case 'S':

             exit(0);

             case 'n':


             break;

             case 'N':
             
             
             break;

             default:

             printf ("opción no valida\n ");

        } 
 
    }
    
    while((ch !='s') || (ch !='S') || (ch != 'n') || (ch != 'N'));
    
}
```

Esto es lo que obtengo en la consola de comandos:

```
¿Esta seguro que desea salir del programa? (s/n):n 

¿Esta seguro que desea salir del programa? (s/n):N 


¿Esta seguro que desea salir del programa? (s/n):m 

opción no valida  

¿Esta seguro que desea salir del programa? (s/n):s 

user@mint:~/Documents/Proyecto/src$
```

Alguien me puede decir que he hecho mal?

Saludos y gracias de antemano,

Yal

Comment: Una opción simple es remover el  loop y dejar solo el switch. Sino debes mejorar las condiciones para que al apretar n salga del loop. Fijate quw tiene todos ORs en las condiciones por lo que siempre va a ser true y quedarse en el loop. Tienes que sumar algún AND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu programa tiene varios errores:

**Uso de `break`**

Una sentencia `break` que está dentro de un `switch`, únicamente sirve para abandonar dicho `switch`. Si esta sentencia se encuentra dentro de un `while`, el `while` seguirá su ejecución habitual.

Te lo comento porque me da la impresión (por cómo está redactada la pregunta) que esperabas que el `break` afectase también al bucle `do-while`

**Chequeos innecesarios**

Estás haciendo los chequeos al revés.

No tiene sentido que tengas el `switch` con un `exit` si luego en el `do-while` vuelves a evaluar la condición del `exit`.

Tras `exit` el programa finaliza, luego esos mismos chequeos en el `do-while` no se van a ejecutar jamás

**Condiciones del `do-while` son incorrectas**

Si unes las condiciones con un `or`, en cuanto una de ellas se cumpla, el resultado final va a ser `true` y el bucle volverá a repetirse.

Es decir

```
while((ch !='s') || (ch !='S') || (ch != 'n') || (ch != 'N'))
```

En este condicional, es **imposible** que `ch` tenga varios valores a la vez, luego si es `'s'` (por poner un ejemplo), la primera condición será falsa.

Sin embargo, al ser `'s'` ya no puede ser `'S'`. Esto hace que la segunda condición sea verdadera. Como todas las condiciones están concatenadas con **OR**, la condición final será **siempre** verdadera

**Solución**

Corrigiendo un poco todo esto, el código podría quedar así:

```
void salir() {
    
    char ch = '\0';

    do{ 
        if (ch != '\0') {
            printf ("opción no valida\n ");
        }

        printf("¿Esta seguro que desea salir del programa? (s/n):");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
    } while((ch !='s') && (ch !='S') && (ch != 'n') & (ch != 'N'));

    if (ch == 's' || ch == 'S')
    {
        exit(0);
    }
 }
```